# How do I uninstall a font?

Tags: mac, font, font-book

I double-clicked a downloaded font and it installed itself in /Users/myuser/Library/Fonts. But all other fonts are installed in /Library/Fonts. Why does it do that by default and how do I uninstall it? I tried disabling and removing it via Font book but it still renders in a web project.

(I am running Mac OS 10.6.8)

Comment: Edited your question for readability. I hope I didn't change the meaning. I don't think I did, but lemme know if I did.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X places installed fonts in the user's Library folder to differentiate between system fonts (located in `/System/Library/Fonts`), OS fonts (`/Library/Fonts`) and user installed fonts (`/Users/~/Library/Fonts`).

You can change this by open Font Book preferences (File>Preferences) and changing the "Default Install Location" option from User to Computer.

Hope this helps.

Added on 1/12/12 at 2:35pm:

Forgot to mention - If you're not able to delete the font from Font Book, try removing it from the `/Users/~/Library/Fonts` directory and emptying the trash. Also, make sure it's not a font that is also in the `/Library/Fonts` directory (preinstalled).